# Using PySpark to write avro with custom schema to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, schema, avro

I'm reading avro files from HDFS into pyspark dataframes, doing some transformations on the data and schema, and wanting to save the dataframes to new avros with the custom schema.  I keep getting a Py4J error.

Here is how I'm trying to write:

```
df.write.format("avro").option("avroSchema", schema).option("recordName", "customRecordName").option("recordNamespace", "namespace.name").save("hdfs://an/hdfs/path/1234")
```

Here is the schema:

```
schema = {
        "namespace": "namespace.name",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "customRecordName",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name":"header", 
            "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Header",
                "fields" : [
                    {"name":"_aField", "type":{"type":"enum", "name":"AField", "symbols":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]}},
                    {"name":"_anotherField", "type":{"type":"enum", "name":"AnotherField", "symbols":["z","y","x","w","v"]}}
                ]
            }
        },
        {"name":"anID", "type":"int"},
        {"name":"type", "type":{"type":"enum", "name":"Type", "symbols":["l","m","n"]}},
        {"name":"name", "type":"string"}
    ]
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 1
----> 1 df.write.format("avro")\
      2 .option("avroSchema", schema)\
      3 .option("recordName", "customRecordName")\
      4 .option("recordNamespace", "namespace.name")\
      5 .save("hdfs://namenode/an/hdfs/path/1234")
      8 #df.write.format('avro').save('hdfs://namenode/an/hdfs/path/1234')

File /opt/spark-3.3.2-bin-without-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:968, in DataFrameWriter.save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    966     self._jwrite.save()
    967 else:
--> 968     self._jwrite.save(path)

File /opt/spark-3.3.2-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()
...
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4650)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2941)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:1433)
    ... 49 more
```

I've tried `json.dumps(schema)` before doing the write, and I've also tried `avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(schema))`.  These also result in Py4J errors.  I've tried `df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")` as well.

I can write avro files to HDFS just fine with

```
df.write.format('avro').save('hdfs://namenode/an/hdfs/path/1234')
```

but it generates an avro schema that doesn't include all the metadata that should be included in the avro schema; hence the custom schema.